# Use Json Server on Admin-on-rest

Tags: json, rest, reactjs, admin-on-rest

I'm doing the Admin-on-rest tutorial, I have done every thing, and now i need to change the json server from json placen holder to the json server (from json place holder).

I have created already the server, I only need to know how to connect the server to react.

I already tried this way:

```
const App = () => (
  <Admin restClient={jsonServerRestClient('http://localhost:5000/')}>
    <Resource name="posts" list={PostList} edit={PostEdit} create={PostCreate} remove={Delete} icon={PostIcon} />
  <Resource name="users" list={UserList} icon={UserIcon} />
 </Admin>
);
```

Comment: Can you explain what doesn't work? Any error?

Comment: http://localhost:5000/ does you api server response you?

Comment: I do not know what happened, the code just star working

Comment: But thanks for the help!!!!

Comment: Then please mark your issue as resolved so it doesn't appear in the list of issues requiring help.

Comment: Where can I close the question if I only talk with other guys in comments?